# How to force wget to use TLS1.2

Tags: wget

The following command when run on a `RHEL8` server results in TLS1.3 negotiation, even though TLS version 1.2 has been specified -

`wget --secure-protocol=TLSv1_2  https://hostname.test.com/1G_elgin_apache --no-check-certificate`

I understand this can be forced with curl as follows -

`curl -k -O https://hostname.test.com/1G_elgin_apache -l --tlsv1.2 --tls-max 1.2`

Is there any way to force wget to initiate a client hello in TLS1.2 ??

Comment: Have you found an answer for this?

Answer (score 3):

Try using flag --secure-protocol. for example:

```
--secure-protocol=TLSv1_1
```